# Trying to match form values with JSON keys, wildcards if no match

Tags: javascript, json

Working on a webpage/form I'm trying to use below JSON structure to change/populate the form.

```
{
    "REGION1": {
        "CODE1": {
            "mandatory": 1,
            "labelId": "labelId",
            "disableSearch": 1,
            "dropdownId": "dropdownId",
            "options": ["opt1", "opt2", "opt3"]
        }
    },
    "*": {
        "CODE1": {
            "mandatory": 0,
            "labelId": "label2Id",
            "disableSearch": 1,
            "dropdownId": "dropdown2Id",
            "options": ["opt1", "opt2", "opt4"]
        }
    }
}
```

For instance, if a user selects "REGION1" and "CODE1" from some dropdowns, ideally I'd like to grab the values later like:

```
var values = myJson[regionText][codeText] // grabbed from dropdowns
```

Now say regionText isn't mapped but codeText is. In theory I want to grab the second object and match the region wildcard. Is there a smart way of:

```
if(values[regionText][codeText] == null) {
    values = values["*"][codeText]
    if(values[regionText][codeText] == null) {
        values = values["*"]["*"]
        //...
    }
}
```

In reality my JSON has 5 layers and if I can avoid 5 layers of if's I'd like to. My current solution is iterating through and matching (not actual JS but pseudocode):

```
foreach(key in values.keys()) {
    if(values[regionText]=="REGION2" or values[regionText]=="*") {
        foreach(key2 in values[key].keys()) { // continue }
    }
}
```

EDIT: first answer almost works but fails in this case where I'm searching "REGION1" and "CODE2". In the below case I need to check "REGION1" (doesn't find "CODE2" then check the "*" region for "CODE2" which is there.

```
{
    "REGION1": {
        "CODE1": {
            "isMandatory": 1,
            "labelId": "id",
            "disableSearch": 1,
            "dropdownId": "id",
            "stakeholders": ["opt1", "opt2"]
        }
    },
    "*": {
        "CODE2": {
            "isMandatory": 1,
            "labelId": "id",
            "disableSearch": 1,
            "dropdownId": "id",
            "stakeholders": ["opt1", "opt2"]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple function like this:

```
function get(values, ...props) {
  let current = values
  for (const prop of props) {
    if (prop in current) {
      current = current[prop]
    } else {
      current = current['*']
    }
  }
  return current
}
```

```js
const values = {
    "REGION1": {
        "CODE1": {
            "mandatory": 1,
            "labelId": "labelId",
            "disableSearch": 1,
            "dropdownId": "dropdownId",
            "options": ["opt1", "opt2", "opt3"]
        }
    },
    "*": {
        "CODE1": {
            "mandatory": 0,
            "labelId": "label2Id",
            "disableSearch": 1,
            "dropdownId": "dropdown2Id",
            "options": ["opt1", "opt2", "opt4"]
        }
    }
}

console.log(get(values, 'eqw', 'CODE1'))

function get(values, ...props) {
  let current = values
  for (const prop of props) {
    if (prop in current) {
      current = current[prop]
    } else {
      current = current['*']
    }
  }
  return current
}
```

### Edit

I've used a recursive function to make it work with the second example

```js
const values = {
  "REGION1": {
    "CODE1": 'REGION1 CODE1'
  },
  "*": {
    "CODE2": '* CODE2'
  }
}

console.log(get(values, 'REGION1', 'CODE2'))

function get(values, ...props) {
  const rec = (current = values, index = 0) => {
    if (index === props.length) return current
    const prop = props[index]
    const val = prop in current && rec(current[prop], index + 1)
    if (val) return val
    const val2 = '*' in current && rec(current['*'], index + 1)
    if (val2) return val2
    return undefined
  }

  return rec()
}
```

Comment: This is clever and 95% working the way I need. I've added a case in my original post where this function would miss the right values.

Comment: Was just going down the recursive route and you beat me to it! Appreciate the help a ton!

Comment: actually had to remove the ```return val``` and ```return val2``` to get all results I needed but looks great now!